# Plotting pie chart based on columns conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a pie plot out of my dataframe. The idea is that I have two columns which indicates whether the data is valid or not. I want to generate a pie chart with four categories, which are valid points (true, true) and also other three categories showing the invalid data, indicating if the data is invalid by the Validity1, by the Validity2 or by both.

So, I have the following dataset:

```
                TimeStamp  Avg. Values  ... Validity1 Validity2
0     2015-02-14 20:30:00      5.1736  ...     False   True
1     2015-02-14 20:40:00      16.6266  ...    True   True
2     2015-02-14 20:50:00      12.7667  ...    True   True
3     2015-02-14 21:00:00      11.6077  ...    False   True
4     2015-02-14 21:10:00       19.6851  ...   True   True
                  ...          ...  ...         ...    ...
1000 2015-06-12 23:30:00       1.699  ...      True  False
1001 2015-06-12 23:40:00       2.2468  ...     False  False
1002 2015-06-12 23:50:00       3.1147  ...     False  False
1003 2015-06-13 00:00:00       6.141  ...      True  False
1004 2015-06-13 00:10:00       3.792  ...      True  False
```

So, one of my ideas was to initially divide the data as the following:

```
data_valid = data.loc[(data.SaDataValid == True) & (data.DataOK == True)]
data_invalid_both = data.loc[(data.Validity1 == False) & (data.Validity2== False)]
data_invalid_1 = data.loc[(data.Validity1 == True) & (data.Validity2 == False)]
data_invalid_2 = data.loc[(data.Validity1 == False) & (data.Validity2 == True)]
```

My question is how to go from that point to be able to plot a pie chart with these 4 categories which includes the conditions of separating the data of Validity1 and Validity 2 into 3 other categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.groupby(['Validity1','Validity2']).size().plot.pie()
```

Test data:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], size=(100,2), p=[0.7,0.3]),
                  columns = ['Validity1','Validity2'])
```

Output:

[image]